# Regex not matching for a String in Scala code

Tags: regex, scala

This Regex is not working for below given string, as below string has “href”. I am using `scala 2.11.11`

```
val p1 = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"")
    val m1 = p1.matcher(bodyString)
    while(m1.find()){
        println(m1.group(1))
    }
```

String:

```
"<p>Is this person trying to advertise a sound card? They dont seem to be answering my questions either </p><p><br /></p><p><a href=\"https://discussion.xyz.com/thread/2524?answerId&#61;25022&amp;page&#61;1\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow opener referrer\">https://discussion.xyz.com/thread/250274?answerId&#61;250722&amp;page&#61;1</a></p>"
```

Please suggest if any other way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the Scala regex API? Use `val p1 = "href=\"(.*?)\"".r` and then `val m1 = p1.findAllMatchIn(bodyString)`. BTW, there is no pattern matching in your example. BTW, the pattern works well on your string.

Comment: Try `Pattern.compile("href=\\\"(.*?)\\\"")`

Comment: @blackdrumb `\"` = `"` in regex as `"` is not any special metacharacter.

Comment: See [this demo](https://rextester.com/FMCH53667).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew strange that yours works... mine works as well.  I would imagine that you need to escape the quotes so that the string does not end at "href=\", so the variable stores `href="(.*?)"`.  Then you would also have to escape the first backslash so that the variable would store `href=\"(.*?)\"`

Comment: Please share a rextester fiddle reproducing your issue if you need a straightforward and working answer.

Answer (score -2):

Your expression seems to be fine, there are just two backslashes in the input string that can be likely included, maybe in this form:

```
href=\\\"(.*?)\\\"
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/PNrZZl/1/)

or if we'd be searching for `https` patterns, we could simplify it to:

```
\\"https?:(.*?)\\"
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/o3GuVK/1/)

and our desired link is in the capturing group `#1`.

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PNrZZl/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: It is the same regex used by OP. Why do you suggest the same regex? ``\"`` = `"` in regex as `"` is not any special metacharacter. *our desired link is in the capturing group `$1`* - no, it is not Perl.

Comment: This is what I posted in the comments.  I was going to post it in the answers after OP verified that it worked.

Comment: Besides, you are testing a wrong input string. See [what input OP has in fact](https://rextester.com/ESZNG56927).